# Get the last working day in the last month of a Quarter using MySql

Tags: mysql

The result of the below query is giving me the last working day in a month.

```
select  DATE_FORMAT(max(dates), '%m-%d-%Y')  Last_day
from
(select dates,@r := @r + 1 as r
FROM
(SELECT @r := 0) r1,
(SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, DATE_ADD('2013-03-01', INTERVAL @row-1 DAY) dates
From
(SELECT @row := 0) r,
(select 1 n union all select 2 n union all select 3 n union all select 4 n union all     select 5 n union all select 6 n) t1,
(select 1 n union all select 2 n union all select 3 n union all select 4 n union all select 5 n union all select 6 n) t2
) num_seq 
where 
dates<DATE_ADD('2013-03-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
and DAYNAME(dates) not in ('Saturday','Sunday') 
order by dates )rTable;
```

The result of the below query is giving me the last day in quarter of particular given day.

```
select MAKEDATE(YEAR('2013-03-01'), 1)+ INTERVAL QUARTER('2013-03-01') QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY a;
```

The issue which i have is to get the last working day from previous, present and next quarter.
Is there a way to get the result using the above both sql into one.

kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the last working days for the previous, present and next quarter, it might be much easier to just compute these dates in your application code and then pass them to the database.

Comment: We need the query so that we can schedule the ETL Job, from the output of the designed stored procedure.